# why do i measure a potential difference when I put my two electrodes in a water bottle?

Tags: multimeter, water

I have a multimeter adjusted in DC tension mode. When I put my two wire connections inside a water container, I measure +120 mV or sometthing less but never zero. Why do I measure a potential difference ?

Comment: I'm betting that that wasn't absolutely pure, non-ionic water. What your saying is you put two metal probes into a weak electrolyte and it produced a small voltage measured using a very high impedance voltmeter. Take at look at the strange world of the potato battery. http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Energy_p010.shtml

Answer (score 1):

This is common, and is because the two probes aren't exactly of the same metal.  They may have started out that way, but over time each was exposed to a different history of corrosion, sweaty fingers, and the like.  The result is that the two probes no longer have exactly the same electro-chemical potential.

Put another way, each probe in the water is acting like half a battery.  Since they aren't identical, they don't produce exactly the same voltage.  The difference between the two half-battery potentials is what the meter is showing you.

Instead of one of the probes directly in the water, try a different metal and connect the probe to that metal out of the water.  That should give a larger difference between the probes.  You can also try other conductive substances, like a graphite rod.